# PL/SQL: How to pass a tablename to a dynamic SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL and I try to have the table name of a `SELECT` dynamically set by a parameter.

This is working fine.

```
DECLARE 
  FUNCTION foo (pat VARCHAR) RETURN NUMBER IS
    tabname VARCHAR (100) := 'my_table';
    n NUMBER := -1;
    sqlcmd VARCHAR (100) := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || tabname || ' WHERE bezeichnung LIKE :1';
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlcmd INTO n USING pat;
    RETURN n;
  END foo;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line (foo ('bla%'));
END;
```

If I try to have `tabname` set by a parameter as it is with `pat` then it fails with ther error :

> invalid table name

```
DECLARE

  FUNCTION defval (pat VARCHAR, offs NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
    tabname VARCHAR (100) := 'A_KGL_EIGENSCHAFTEN';
    n NUMBER := -1;
    sqlcmd VARCHAR (100) := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM :1 WHERE bezeichnung LIKE :2';
  BEGIN     
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlcmd INTO n USING tabname, pat;
    dbms_output.put_line ('tabname: ' || tabname);
    dbms_output.put_line ('n: ' || n);
    RETURN n;
  END defval;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line (defval ('LPG.GAX.%.DBE', 2));
END;
```

How can I set the table name by this bound parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking to prevent the sql injection using concate then you can use the `sys.DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(p_table_name)`

So your string variable should look like this:

```
sqlcmd VARCHAR (100) := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' 
                        || sys.DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(tabname) 
                        || ' WHERE bezeichnung LIKE :1';
```

You can learn more about `DBMS_ASSERT` from [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_assert.htm).

Answer (score 2):

> You cannot use bind arguments to pass the names of schema objects to a dynamic SQL statement.

From the Oracle documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm

So yes, your 2nd query is bound to fail. Your concat in the first one seem the good way to go.